# Add/Remove html element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to show form dynamically according to request.

HTML

```
<label for="Type" class="required">Type</label>
<br>
<input id="f01" name="fieldid[]" type="hidden" value="23">
<input class="23" id="01" required="1" name="type" type="checkbox" value="g_magic"><span>   G magic</span>
<div>
  <div id="div0g_magic"></div>
</div>
<input id="f02" name="fieldid[]" type="hidden" value="23">
<input class="23" id="02" required="1" name="type" type="checkbox" value="four_five"><span>   Four five</span>
<div>
  <div id="div0four_five"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#01").on("change", function () {
  var valueid = $("#01").val();
  var fieldid = $("#f01").val();
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    send(valueid, fieldid);
  } else {
    $("#div0" + valueid).empty();
  }
});

function send(valueid, fieldid) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    success: function (response) {

      $("#div0" + valueid).html(response.responseText);

    },
    error: function (response) {
      $("#div0" + valueid).html(response);
    }
  });
}

$("#02").on("change", function () {
  var valueid = $("#02").val();
  var fieldid = $("#f02").val();
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    send(valueid, fieldid);
  } else {
    $("#div0" + valueid).empty();
  }
});

function send(valueid, fieldid) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20JS!',
    success: function (response) {

      $("#div0" + valueid).html(response.responseText);

    },
    error: function (response) {
      $("#div0" + valueid).html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

CSS

```
.required:after {
  color: #e32 !important;
  content: ' * ' !important;
  display: inline !important;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: where is your code?Give your code

Comment: you forgot include link of your code in your question

Comment: dude you forgot to link your code... :P

Comment: Sorry I couldn't add my link properly ..  this is the link https://jsfiddle.net/ycfvxqty/5/

Comment: You couldn't add the link properly because you are supposed to enter your code *directly in the question* rather than just providing a link. Please [edit] your question to show the relevant part of your code.

Comment: I have added your code to your question. However your question is still completely unclear. What is your code doing? How is that different to what you expect/want? Give details. What errors, if any, are being presented? The basics of asking an IT question apply here just like anywhere else. If you ask questions like this in the workplace you won't be in the workplace very long.

Answer (score 0):

method send() making conflict. Give different name for send() in on change function.

Answer (score -2):

Removing html content from an html element

```
document.getElementById("element_id").innerHTML=""
```

Adding html content to an html element

```
document.getElementById("element_id").innerHTML="<p>This is a new content</p>"
```

Answer (score -2):

I can't see your code, so I can't be completely sure on this, but it sounds like you want to dynamically show/hide a form or forms depending on a request. This is pretty easy to accomplish with jQuery. You would use this code:

```
$("#element-id").hide();
```

or

```
$("#element-id").show();
```

Where #element-id is the id of the element you want to show/hide. If you want to avoid ID's or hide multiple elements at once, you can give the elements a class like 'element-class', and then you would use:

```
$(".element-class").hide();
```

If this isn't what you were looking to accomplish, please update/comment and hopefully someone can help more!